# Generate a string that is 1024 digits long based on MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to generate a string that is alpha and/or numeric that is based off the Month Day and Year that it was created. The string must be at least 1024 in length. Basically like a token that can be used between two machines only on the date it was created. The code I have so far is this:

```
Dim temp As String = DateTime.Now.Day ^ DateTime.Now.Month ^ DateTime.Now.Year
    MsgBox(temp)
```

But it just overloads and doesn't do me much good. What I am trying to do is, computer 'A' encrypts a file using a token based on the date it was created. Computer 'B' will then decrypt it using the same token. It doesn't necessarily have to be by date but both machines will need to know what the token is.

Comment: Please add the code you got so far to your question. Are there any additional requirements the token needs to fulfill?

Comment: I was thinking of using something like this: Dim temp As String = DateTime.Now.Day ^ DateTime.Now.Month ^ DateTime.Now.Year
        MsgBox(temp) but it just overloads

Comment: Add to your question by editing it, please.

Comment: There is no regular data type that can hold a number with 1024 digits, so you would need something like a `BigInteger` if you want that. You only have eight digits of information in the date, so where do you like the other 1016 digits to come from? What do you need all the digits for anyway? The strongest symmetric encryption algorithms uses 256 bit keys, so what are you going to use that needs thousands of bits?

Comment: You could use the integer represented by YYYYMMDD as the seed value for a new System.Random and then build your string using values from the Random object.

Comment: You know the NET framework comes with a compleat set of Cryptography routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a 1024 long string called "token"... you can also alter how long this string will be valid by changing the second to minute or hour or day or month or year in this line of code  "token += getMD5Hash(Now.Second + i)"

```
Public Shared Function getMD5Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)
    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
    Dim strResult As String = ""
    Dim b As Byte
    For Each b In bytesToHash
        strResult += b.ToString("x2")
    Next
    Return strResult
End Function



Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim token As String
    For i = 0 To 31
        token += getMD5Hash(Now.Second + i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I believe this will work for what I need it to unless anyone else has a better idea.

```
        Dim result As Byte()
        Dim sha As New SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim key As String = Nothing
        result = sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( _
                                 Date.Today.ToString("MMddyyyy")))
        key = System.Convert.ToBase64String(result)
```